# Javascript convert an array of objects to 1 array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array defined:

```
$scope.exportData = [];
```

and then I do an api call and it returns 3 objects in my array.

```
[Object, Object, Object] //from Console Log

0: Object
  Name: "Steve"
  Age: 30
  Sex: "M"
1: Object
  Name: "James"
  Age: 25
  Sex: "M"
2: Object
  Name: "Joe"
  Age: 20
  Sex: "M"
```

what I am looking to do here is take the objects inside the $scope.exportData and turn them in arrays so I have 5 arrays inside $scope.exportData like so:

```
[Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]]
   0: Array[3]
      "Name" : "Steve"
      "Age" : 30
      "Sex" : "M"
   1: Array[3]
      "Name" : "James"
      "Age" : 25
      "Sex" : "M"
   2: Array[3]
      "Name" : "Joe"
      "Age" : 20
      "Sex" : "M"
```

how would I do this? Thanks, any help would be appreciated

Comment: why would you actually wants to do like this, having object is easier to access then the array of clusters.

Comment: I have code that goes through each array and puts in the csv file, making these objects in arrays would just be easier for me.

Comment: You can't, an array can only have numerical indices, not key / value pairs, as then it would be an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They try like this, if data is the array of objects, then

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.exportData.length; i++) {
    var arr = [];
    for(j in $scope.exportData[i]) {
        arr.push($scope.exportData[i][j]);
    }
    $scope.exportData[i] = arr;
}
```

Comment: do I replace data with $scope.exportData?

Comment: I replaced data.length and (data[i]) with $scope.exportData and replaced data[i] = with newArray and its pretty much working, it just each value returns ""Name":"Steve"" how would I get it to only have "Steve" as the value?

Comment: There are 53 items Name, Age and Sex were just an example. I tried to do another split for : but got an error :( undefined is not a function :(

Comment: Try now... i thought only three fields are there. now i have changed for n fields

Comment: @Bharath why you use `arr.slice()`? Should be like: http://jsbin.com/yimif/1/edit

Comment: I personally use slice as its act as array clone in javascript. If we dont to use it, it will probably stick to its reference and continues to change.

Comment: @Bharath +1 I just edited your example to make the code more readable. And again `.slice()` makes no sense to me... (P.S. try to use any sort of readable code, specially if you notice OP struggles with JS basics)